# Rails: Two identical submit buttons on the form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have one form but because of the design I can't use the same button on the mobile and web. I created two buttons, one is hidden on the mobile, one on desktop. However, one of them does not work.

Is there a way to have two submit buttons that do the exact same thing? I found lots of examples where two submit buttons do different thing. Mine looks something like this:

```
<%= form_tag form_path, class: "form", method: "GET" do %>
  <%= check_box_tag(:pet_dog) %>
  <%= label_tag(:pet_dog, "I own a dog") %>
  <%= check_box_tag(:pet_cat) %>
  <%= label_tag(:pet_cat, "I own a cat") %>

  <%= button_tag class:"mobile button" do%>
    SUBMIT
  <% end %>

  <%= button_tag class:"desktop button" do%>
    SUBMIT
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Which one doesn't work? What happens if you remove the working button, does the non-working button start working? Is the code different for one versus the other? Maybe there's something wrong with the submit code for one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an id for your form:

```
form_tag form_path, class: "form", id: "my_form" method: "GET"
```

And add `form` attribute to your buttons:

```
<%= button_tag class:"mobile button", form: "my_form" do%>
  SUBMIT
<% end %>

<%= button_tag class:"desktop button", form: "my_form" do%>
  SUBMIT
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can install: https://github.com/fnando/browser
And try to use:

```
<%= button_tag class: "#{browser.mobile? ? 'mobile' : 'desktop'} button" do%>
  SUBMIT
<% end %>
```